# Randomly Modify Entries in CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have a CSV file containing data like this:

```
DateTime, product_x, product_y, product_z
2018-01-02 00:00:00,945,1318,17.12
2018-01-03 00:00:00,958,1322,17.25
...
```

I want to use Python and Pandas to modify the values for product_x, product_y and product_z by some random amount - say adding a random value from -3 - +3 to each, and then writing the result back to a CSV.

EDIT: I need each cell shifted by a different amount (except for random coincidences).

How do I do this please?

Comment: Do you want want a single random number for all the cells, or different cell can be shifted by a different random number?

Comment: Each cell shifted by a different amount.

Comment: @RobinAndrews - Can you add what means `each cell shifted by a different amount`  by expected ouput?

Comment: A random value between -3 and +3 added to each cell individually, not the same random value added to all cells. "Cells" means "values for the products."

Comment: @RobinAndrews - Understand, so my solution working correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) with columns names in list for generate `2d array` and add to original columns filtered in same list:

```
cols = ['product_x','product_y','product_y']

#dynamic columns names
#cols = df.filter(like='product').columns
df[cols] += np.random.randint(-3, 3, size=(len(df.index), len(cols)))
```

---

```
print (df)
              DateTime  product_x  product_y  product_z
0  2018-01-02 00:00:00        947       1320      17.12
1  2018-01-03 00:00:00        958       1323      17.25
```

Comment: This basically works, but I get some odd results like `97,2018-05-24 00:00:00,915,1306,14.600000000000001. Any ideas how to avoid this?
`

Comment: @RobinAndrews - so problem with precision of floats?

Comment: It looks like the way Python is handling floats, yes. I'd like just one or two decimal places for the values, as there are in the original data.

Comment: @RobinAndrews - Then add to my solution `df[cols] = df[cols].round(2)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.